# Can I get my payment back on a vacation booked with a company that went into receivership?

Tags: canada, credit-card, deposits, consumer-protection, receivership

My friend booked a summer vacation with a resort/inn located in Ontario that has just gone into receivership.  She paid in FULL with a credit card about a month ago.

Is there any way to get her money back?

Comment: Welcome back!  Which country / local is the inn?  What method of payment did your friend use?  How long ago did the payment happen?

Comment: Thanks :) Figured this was the best forum for the question!  The inn is in Ontario, and was paid by credit card about a month ago.

Comment: I will let an expert answer, but I would assume she can initiate a charge back on her credit card for services not received.  In the US we have two months to do it, so better get to it.

Comment: Thanks - she's started that with her credit card company so we'll see what comes out of that! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5):

You should start a dispute with the credit card company, and they might be able to recover some/all of the money. Usually, if you act fast enough, credit companies (on the merchant's side) have enough of the deposits not yet disbursed to the merchant, and they'll just reverse the charge. The earlier you start the process - the more chances you have.

Otherwise you'll have to sue, I'm not familiar with the Canadian legal system.

Comment: +1 - Need to read the fine print on the card. It has nothing to do with how fast the card disbursed the payment and everything to do with time since the charge.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer not at all. If the merchant is bankrupt, chargeback is useless **unless** the merchant's bank has the money on the account. Otherwise its just one more debt for the bankruptcy, and that's why you'd have to actually sue.

Comment: @littleadv - I'd need to see the fine print for the card in question. Two years ago, my wife and a friend bought custom furniture and the store went under. Our credit card issued a credit with little effort. The friend wrote a check and never saw a dime back.